# Sum of Numbers as Distinct Primes

Tags: c#, algorithm, primes

```
//List Style


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class pr{

    static public void Main (){

            int n, i, j, k, l, sum,flag = 0;
            //int sum = i+j;
            //int k = (n-i);
            //int l = (n-j);

            //System.Console.WriteLine ("Enter a number");
            //n = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());

            //List <int> primes = new List <int>(); //list to handle the numbers
            //HashSet <int> myPrimes = new HashSet <int> (primes);


                 System.Console.WriteLine ("Enter a number");
                 n = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
                 //myPrimes.Add(n);
                 //myPrimes.Add(i);
                 //myPrimes.Add(j);

                // var count = string.Join(", ", primes);
                  //System.Console.WriteLine("The value of n is {0}",myPrimes);

                    for(i=3; i<n/2; i++){

                        for(j=3; j<n/2; j++){

                            if(checkPrime(i) == 1){

                                if(checkPrime(j) == 1){

                                    if (checkPrime(n-i) == 1){

                                        if (checkPrime(n-j) == 1){

                                                //if(i == j){
                                                //sum = i+j;


                                            System.Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}+{2}\n",n,i,n-i);
                                        //}

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                            if (flag == 0 && (n-i) <= 0 && (n-j) <= 0){ //check to avoid dupes

                                    if (n <= 0 && i <= 0 && j <= 0){

                                        Console.Write("{0}\n",n);
                                    }


                            }


                        }
                    }

    }

            public static int checkPrime(int n){

                int i, j, flag = 1;

                for (i = 2; i<=(Math.Sqrt(n)); i++){ 

                    for (j = 2; j<=(Math.Sqrt(n)); j++){


                        if (n%i == 0 && n%j == 0 ){ //even number check

                                i++;
                                j++;
                                flag = 0;
                    } 

                }

            }

                return flag;
            }






}
```

So I have been experimenting with this for a while now. I cant seem to print all possible solutions. For example for 24 I am able to print 7+17 but not 2+5+17. There are also some answers being repeated and this might have to do with the fact that I dont have duplicate checks. I tried to push the integers in a list and then use a hashset to only have distinct integers but I got stuck and tried to brute force it. All the numbers to be printed are supposed to be distinct prime integers. I dont understand how to print all distinct numbers and is there an elegant way to print out all the possible.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you check your code? seems the bracket is not closed properly

Comment: Also a better indentation helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's elegant enough for you, but I've just mashed a dirty way to make it work:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        var numberToSum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var primesInRange = GetPrimesUpTo(numberToSum);
        var foundSolutions = primesInRange.SubSetsOf().Where(prime => prime.Sum() == numberToSum);

        foreach (var solution in foundSolutions.ToList())
        {
            var formatOperation = solution
                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                .Aggregate((a, n) => a + " + " + n) + " = " + numberToSum;

            Console.WriteLine(formatOperation);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> GetPrimesUpTo(int end)
    {
        var primes = new HashSet<int>();

        for (var i = 2; i <= end; i++)
        {
            var ok = true;

            foreach (var prime in primes)
            {
                if (prime * prime > i)
                    break;

                if (i % prime == 0)
                {
                    ok = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (ok)
                primes.Add(i);
        }

        return primes;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (!source.Any())
            return Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1);

        var element = source.Take(1);

        var haveNots = SubSetsOf(source.Skip(1));
        var haves = haveNots.Select(set => element.Concat(set));

        return haves.Concat(haveNots);
    }
```

I've found your solution quite dirty so I divided the problem to be more understandable. GetPrimesUpTo returns all prime number from 2 to the number you've provided in the input, SubSetsOf returns combination of numbers that summed up equals the input number you've provided and finally the foreach in Main produces formatted output that is easy on the eye. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok I understand where i went wrong in my implementation now. I was trying to add "n". I was only brute forcing my way for 2 different solutions rather than calculating for the rest of the solutions. Could you please explain the last past of your solution for me. Starting from"public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)" I want to replicate this using my version.

Comment: It takes list of items and use recursion to return every possible subset of it i.e: if you provide an array of prime numbers [2, 3, 5] it will produce [2, 3, 5], [2, 3], [2, 5], [2], [3, 5], [3]. Having this information we can sum every each of them and compare to value we want to get. These will be possible solutions. It's far from optimal but the most self-explanatory as I could do. Do you get it now?

Comment: Yeah it makes some sense now. Sorry I basically started coding in C# from a week or so ago. But from looking at my code were there any glaring errors or problems other than the whole distinct prime number part. I am going to try to implement as much as I can in my code based on the information given here as I have to repeat this task in other languages.

Comment: When you have a nested structure like in your sample
(for -> for -> if -> if -> if -> if)
you can be 100% sure something is not right. Nobody can possibly follow the logic and it's a very bad practice in all languages. There's not enough place here, so I'll add another response and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you have collection of primes and `IsPrime` method

```
private static int[] primes = new[] { 
  2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37 };

private static bool IsPrime(int value) {
  return primes.Contains(value);
}
```

You can implement recoursive solution

```
private List<List<int>> ToListOfPrimes(int value, List<int> parts = null) {
  if (null == parts)
    parts = new List<int>();

  List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();

  if (value == 0) {
    result.Add(parts.ToList());

    return result;
  }

  int minPrime = parts.Count <= 0 ? 0 : parts[parts.Count - 1];

  if (value <= minPrime)
    return result;

  // not that efficient: binary search will be a better choice here 
  for (int i = 0; i < primes.Length; ++i) {
    int p = primes[i];

    if (p <= minPrime)
      continue;
    else if (p > value)
      break;

    var list = parts.ToList();
    list.Add(p);

    var outcome = ToListOfPrimes(value - p, list);

    foreach (var solution in outcome)
      result.Add(solution);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Test

```
var result = ToListOfPrimes(28);

string report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(line => String.Join(", ", line)));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome (`28`)

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11
2, 3, 23
2, 7, 19
3, 5, 7, 13
5, 23
11, 17
```

For `24`

```
2, 3, 19
2, 5, 17
5, 19
7, 17
11, 13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to implement it in other languages just throw your solution to rubbish bin. You should be more explicit about what is happening during execution. Nested for loops with multiple if statements are not explicit at all. What's even worse in the sample - you'll need to add new for loop every time you want more numbers in the sum. I do believe it's hard to understand it for a novice, but I find recursion the only way to go here.

See for yourself:

1. it's hard to say why output of your program is wrong, because of the logic
2. Variables should be named meaningfully so you know what they store instead of blind guessing.
3. Your checkPrime method returns int even though you return 0 or 1 so it should really return bool type

Use debugger and a piece of paper to understand how recursion works either in my previous answer or the one provided by Dmitry Bychenko